# Setting function name (for logging) when using prototype in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm using prototypes to define an object in javascript.

e.g.

```
Listerly.prototype.init = function() {

    this.storage = new ListerlyStorage();
    this.mainView = new ListerlyMainView();
}
```

Everything works fine, but I'm also trying to limit my console logging using the following very simple logging method:

```
Listerly.prototype.log = function(message) {
    if (this.loggingEnabled) {
        if (arguments && arguments.callee && arguments.callee.caller) {
            var methodName = arguments.callee.caller.name;
            console.log("Method name: "+ methodName);
            if (this.logMethods["*"] || this.logMethods[methodName]) {
                if (methodName) console.log(methodName + ":" + message);
                else console.log(message);
            }
        } else {
            console.log(message);
        }
    }
};
```

The problem is that the functions defined using the prototype don't have a function name, so `arguments.callee.caller.name` is blank.

Is there any clean way to set the function name? I've tried iterating through the prototype after I'm done and setting the `.name` field on each function but that doesn't seem to work.

There's an ugly workaround, which pollutes the global namespace by doing this:

```
function listerly_finishedLoadingUser(user) {
    this.user = user;
    this.mainView.setUser(user);
}
Listerly.prototype.finishedLoadingUser = listerly_finishedLoadingUser;
```

Was hoping there's a cleaner way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[The function name/identifier is optional in function expressions](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13):

```
Listerly.prototype.finishedLoadingUser =
  function listerly_prototype_finishedLoadingUser (user) {
    // …
  };
```

You can use the function name within the function for recursion in strict mode, where [`arguments.callee` is forbidden](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.6).

Note that the identifier also becomes available outside the function in older (borken) JScript versions, so choose it wisely. Also there may be an (unspecified) limit to the identifier length.

The (read-only) `name` property that you used is [only a de-facto standard for now](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3afunction_name_property). Where unavailable, you might be able to obtain the function name from function serialization, that is, converting the `Function` instance to string and extracting the identifier part (as I did in [JSX:object.js](http://pointedears.de/wsvn/JSX/trunk/object.js)):

```
/**
 * Returns the name of a function
 *
 * @param {Function|String} aFunction
 * @return {string}
 *   The name of a function if it has one; the empty string otherwise.
 */
getFunctionName: function (aFunction) {
  /* Return the empty string for null or undefined */
  return (aFunction != null
           && typeof aFunction.name != "undefined" && aFunction.name)
    || (String(aFunction).match(/^\s*function\s+([A-Za-z_]\w*)/) || [, ""])[1];
},
```

*In general, function serialization is unreliable.*

Also note that the `caller` property of the `arguments` object and of `Function` instances is proprietary.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I missed that you could put the function name in the prototype setter call.

Comment: @AkshayRangnekar “prototype setter call” is *nonsense terminology*. You are *defining* a `Function` (instance) by *function expression*, and *assigning* a reference to it to a property of an (prototype) object. Nothing is called here, and a setter is something else entirely. You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The `name` property is special, you cannot change its value in most JavaScript implementation.

Custom function names were a part of ECMAScript 6 discussions, see the [strawman proposal](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman%3aname_property_of_functions) and the [final proposal](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3afunction_name_property).

In the ES6 compliant browsers, you should get the expected function name even with prototype functions:

```
Listerly.prototype.finishedLoadingUser = function() { }
console.log(Listerly.prototype.finishedLoadingUser.name);
// prints "finishedLoadingUser"
```

If you are looking for a solution working in all browsers, you can transpile ES6 sources to ES5 using Google's [Traceur compiler](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler).

Alternatively you can use a different property to store your custom function name:

```
// in the logger
var methodName = arguments.callee.caller.name ||
                 arguments.calee.caller.myCustomName;

// in the property iterator
for (var key in obj) {
  obj[key].myCustomName = key;
}
```

Comment: There is no `displayName` property in this WebKit-based browser, and you appear to be missing the point.

Comment: The purpose of the strawman/proposal is to codify the de-facto standard. By that, your first code would output "anonymous" to the console, *as you can read in the proposal*.

Comment: `var f = function () {}; f.displayName = "foo"; f` prints `function () {}` to the script console of Chromium 33.0.1750.152 Debian jessie/sid (256984). `f.name` prints `""`. No difference with `console.log(f)` or `console.log(f.name)`. Apparently this is a feature of Apple WebCore only. (That you can add properties to `Function` instances is not a WebKit feature.)

Comment: "Apparently this is a feature of Apple WebCore only." - that's entirely possible. Keep in mind that as of April 2013, Chrome is powered by Blink, a Google's fork of WebKit. I tested a similar code in Safari on OSX 10.9 and console.log did not pick the displayName property. If you check the webkit patch 42478, you can see that displayName is used by the CPU profiler.

Comment: I am not using Chrome, I am using Chromium. Blink is a *layout engine*, not a script engine. My point is that this has nothing to do with WebKit, it has to do with the ECMAScript implementation in WebKit, (Apple) JavaScriptCore, and the DOM implementation in WebKit, (Apple) WebCore. As Chrome/Chromium uses Google V8 as script engine (which you should know given your profile), the feature you claimed to exist in “WebKit-based browsers” isn't there. Please stop talking about things without having the minimum clue. Thanks.